# After taking picture using camera , black screen comes for few seconds (2 or 3 seconds)

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

After taking picture using camera , black screen comes for few seconds (2 or 3 seconds) before the UI layout is shown. I use asynchronous task to get the saved file as shown below. The functionality is working fine. But the user experience is bad because of few seconds black screen.

Camera Intent code

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File imagefile=null;
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        try {
            imagefile = File.createTempFile("zicu", ".jpg", storageDir);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        pictureFilePath = imagefile.getAbsolutePath();
        Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                "com.mmxyz.zicu.fileprovider",
                imagefile);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 2);
```

`onActivityResult` code

```
if ((requestCode == 2))
        {
            
          Feedcamera fc= new Feedcamera();
           fc.execute("0");
           var_textview_error.setText("Processing....");
}
```

**Asynchronous task**

```
private class Feedcamera extends AsyncTask<String, Void, File> {

        protected File doInBackground(String... urls) {
            
            File imgFile = new  File(pictureFilePath);
            return imgFile;


        }


        protected void onPostExecute(File imgFile) {


            if(imgFile.exists())            {
                var_imageview_browse.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(imgFile));
            }
```

Comment: Did you try on multiple devices?

Comment: yes. issue is with low , medium range android mobiles.